# read.table() error, even though all elements are present

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

I'm getting an error with read.table():

```
data <- read.table(file, header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep="@")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 160 did not have 28 elements
```

I checked line 160, and it did have 28 elements (it had 27 @ symbols).

I checked all of the 30242 lines there were 816534 @ symbols, which is 27 per line, so I'm pretty sure every single line has 28 elements. I also checked the file to confirm that there were no @ symbols anywhere else other than as separators.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

edit: Line 160 of file

```
158@Mental state: 1. Overall clinical symptoms@MD@S@2002@CMP-005@02@20.67@23.58@Clozapine versus typical neuroleptic medication for schizophrenia@IV@4.47@02@SENSITIVITY ANALYSIS - CHINESE TRIALS@CD000059@6.94@Fixed@16@5@2@45@Chinese trials@YES@Xia 2002 (CPZ)@STD-Xia-2002-_x0028_CPZ_x0029_@579@566@40
```

edit2: Line 161 of file

```
159@Length of surgery (minutes)@MD@Y@1995@CMP-001@01@59.0@47.0@Gamma and other cephalocondylic intramedullary nails versus extramedullary implants for extracapsular hip fractures in adults@IV@23.9@01@Summary: Femoral nail (all types) versus sliding hip screw (SHS)@CD000093@13.3@Random@12@1@1@53@Gamma nail@YES@O'Brien 1995@STD-O_x0027_Brien-1995@958@941@49
```

Comment: Have a go reading in sections of your data around the problem line, using the `skip` and `nrows` arguments , to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: For some reason, when I used read.csv with the sep="@" argument, it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm... maybe you needed to set `fill=TRUE` in `read.table` . (although that would suggest a problem that `fill` is accounting for, which should be looked at)

Comment: What does line #160 look like?

Comment: **Show us line 160, already.** There might be some escaping.

Comment: Try using some of the other arguments, like `strip.white`, `flush`, etc.  The defaults for `read.csv` and `read.table` are not the same

Comment: If you have a hash symbol (#) in a line, read.table will treat it as a comment (ignoring it and everything after it), while the read.csv default is comment.char="", which won't behave that way, so that could be the reason.

Comment: @user2060, CSV is a loosely-defined term meaning "text format with constant column widths" ; `read.csv()` in R is nothing more than [`read.table(...,header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) - it's the same code. Regardless what your separator character, the underlying issue will be the same.` read.csv()` users can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Uh, actually it means "comma-separated values"

Comment: Also, I think since you have header=TRUE, the problem is actually at line 161 of the file.

Comment: Could maybe be the ' in O'Brien, which you could get around with quote="" as long as that doesn't break something else; but in my test that gave a different error message ("incomplete final line found by readTableHeader")

Comment: `read.table(file, header=T, sep="@", comment.char="", quote="\"")` seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that there is a newline character that needs to be recognized by the `quote` argument.  Let's have a look.

```
txt <- c(
    "158@Mental state: 1. Overall clinical symptoms@MD@S@2002@CMP-005@02@20.67@23.58@Clozapine versus typical neuroleptic medication for schizophrenia@IV@4.47@02@SENSITIVITY ANALYSIS - CHINESE TRIALS@CD000059@6.94@Fixed@16@5@2@45@Chinese trials@YES@Xia 2002 (CPZ)@STD-Xia-2002-_x0028_CPZ_x0029_@579@566@40", 
    "159@Length of surgery (minutes)@MD@Y@1995@CMP-001@01@59.0@47.0@Gamma and other cephalocondylic intramedullary nails versus extramedullary implants for extracapsular hip fractures in adults@IV@23.9@01@Summary: Femoral nail (all types) versus sliding hip screw (SHS)@CD000093@13.3@Random@12@1@1@53@Gamma nail@YES@O'Brien 1995@STD-O_x0027_Brien-1995@958@941@49"
)
```

We can use `count.fields()` to preview the field lengths in the file. With a normal `sep = "@"` and nothing else, we get an NA in between the lines, and incorrect counts

```
count.fields(textConnection(txt), sep = "@")
# [1] 28 NA 24
```

But when we recognize the newline separator in `quote`, it returns the correct lengths

```
count.fields(textConnection(txt), sep = "@", quote = "\n")
# [1] 28 28
```

So, I recommend you add `quote = "\n"` to your `read.table` call and see if that solves it. It did for me

```
read.table(text = txt, sep = "@")
# [1] V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

df <- read.table(text = txt, sep = "@", quote = "\n")
dim(df)
# [1]  2 28
anyNA(df)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure why.  I have a hunch it's because a few of these substrings look like unicode hexdigit characters, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. This answer helped, but **quote="\n"** only worked up to a point. There was an element in the file that had a **"** as a character, so I had to use the default for **quote**. I also had **#** in one of the elements, so I had to use **comment.char=""**. The help for **read.table()** referenced **scan()** in a couple spots, so I checked it out and found the **allowEscapes** argument that has **False** as the default. I added that to my **read.table()** call and set it to **True**. Here is the full command that worked for me:
**read.table(file="filename.csv", header=T, sep=",", comment.char="", allowEscapes=T)**
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me out a bunch,. comment.char="" is the way to go.